# ng-grid not working in IE8

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ng-grid

I'm going nuts trying to figure out why ng-grid isn't working in IE8.  I get this error: `Expected identifier, string or number ng-grid-2.0.5.debug.js, line 1535 character 17`.

I'm copying an example straight from the ng-grid homepage (all the examples there load correctly, by the way). Anyone have an idea here?

I would put up a Plnkr or fiddle, but neither will even load in IE8, so it kind of defeats the purpose.

using Angular 1.0.4, jQuery 1.8.1, ng-grid 2.0.5

html

```
<html ng-app="myApp">  
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Getting Started With ngGrid Example</title>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ng-grid.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ng-grid-2.0.5.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.gridStyle {
  border: 1px solid rgb(212,212,212);
  width: 400px; 
  height: 300px;
}
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                     {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                     {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                     {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                     {name: "Enos", age: 34}];
    $scope.gridOptions = { 
        data: 'myData',
        columnDefs: [{field:'name', displayName:'Name'}, {field:'age', displayName:'Age'}]
    };
});
```

Comment: what do you mean fiddle won't load in IE8. Always works for me

Comment: Still not loading for me.  Maybe it's an access issue through my work computer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out the answer was not so obvious.  There was a bug in ng-grid 2.0.5 where the devs were using the Javascript forEach method in one spot instead of angular.forEach.  This is not supported by IE8 and was causing the error. I submitted it to the group and they'll fix it, but for now I just made the change.

Comment: Was it just line 1418 that you had to fix?  That made it better for me, but it still doesn't render correctly.

Comment: That was the only fix I had to make.  Things seem fine for me now.  I submitted the issue on GitHub and it's corrected in the next release.

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer requires special treatment for accommodating AngularJS.
Please read this.

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

Comment: Done all that.  The problem only started happening when I added ng-grid.