# ng-grid not rendering correctly in IE8

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-8, ng-grid

I have a ng-grid view that does not display correctly with IE in IE8 Standards Document Mode. The problem is that the CSS styles created dynamically by Angular that control the column widths do not appear to be rendered.

The solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16367791/ng-grid-not-working-in-ie8) does not apply, as I am using the newer version of the grid in which the reported bug has been fixed.

Debugging the javascript, the following error is occurring in the ng-grid script:

```
SCRIPT65535: Unexpected call to method or property access. 
ng-grid-2.0.6.js, line 311 character 13
```

Does anyone know a workaround for this?

Using versions: angularJS 1.0.7, ng-grid 2.0.6, JQuery 1.9.1.

Answer (score 0):

I am using ng-grid and stuck supporting IE8. I do not have this issue. What is the compile time of the ng-grid.js file that you are using? If I look at my line 311 it's related to setColLeft. Is this the same for you?

Can you link to the version of ng-grid you are using? Here is their latest: https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/blob/fb117189cc1f0c6f8d4a3d926c41601168c348b7/build/ng-grid.js

Comment: I was using ng-grid 2.0.6. However, this issue has now been fixed in 2.0.7.